# what will be the simple mysql query for this

Tags: mysql

I want to get the customer info where customer id should be 2 and the log_id should be maximum value
i tried below query but it is fetching first record found.

What will be the simple query

```
mysql> select * from log_customer where customer_id =2 group by customer_id having max(log_id);
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| log_id | visitor_id | customer_id | login_at            | logout_at | store_id |
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
|      2 |         56 |           2 | 2010-02-19 19:34:45 | NULL      |        1 | 
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from log_customer where customer_id =2 limit 5;
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| log_id | visitor_id | customer_id | login_at            | logout_at           | store_id |
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|      2 |         56 |           2 | 2010-02-19 19:34:45 | NULL                |        1 | 
|      3 |        114 |           2 | 2010-02-23 17:31:55 | NULL                |        1 | 
|     31 |       1854 |           2 | 2010-03-08 18:31:28 | 2010-03-08 18:56:49 |        1 | 
|     32 |       1992 |           2 | 2010-03-09 01:12:43 | NULL                |        1 | 
|     33 |       2304 |           2 | 2010-03-09 14:42:39 | NULL                |        1 | 
+--------+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

**Please do not suggest** `order by log_id desc` I don't want to get in this way

Comment: "Please do not suggest order by log_id desc I don't want to get in this way" --- **argue** this please

Comment: it is a lot of things you can to learn. But turning **simple and fast** queries into **slow and hard to understand** monsters is not a good direction.

Comment: but that original idea is the best, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I agree with you all, I think I have to get it by traditional way. Thanks for your attention

Comment: One thing about omitting the `WHERE Customer_Id = 2` in the outer SELECT in the answers: check what the execution plan looks like! Depending on what indexes you have it may be better to have it in the query nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     SELECT  *
       FROM log_customer
      WHERE customer_id = 2
        AND log_id = (Select Max(Log_id)
                        FROM log_Customer
                       WHERE customer_id = 2)
```

That should do the trick

Edit without the Where:

```
     SELECT  *
       FROM log_customer
      WHERE log_id = (Select Max(Log_id)
                        FROM log_Customer
                       WHERE customer_id = 2)
```

Comment: There is no `TOP` in mysql, replace it with `LIMIT 1` in the end.

Comment: TOP 1 is sql server syntax, you want `LIMIT 1`

Comment: MySQL doesnt do *TOP*, its *LIMIT*

Comment: Thanks everyone who caught that.

Comment: From the OP question **Please do not suggest order by log_id desc I don't want to get in this way**

Comment: @zerkms  I know this way I can get but I wanted to know if there is any other way to do this

Comment: @Shakti Singh: argue why `ORDER BY + LIMIT` is not a correct answer and you need an alternative solution. Or you put on your trousers from the head just because it is an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: @Stefan: Can you remove the WHERE customer_id = 2 from the outer query?

Comment: @Shakti Singh: Yes, assuming all of your log_id's are unique.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes all are unique I think not need to put a condition in outer query

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from log_customer 
left join
(select max(log_id) as max_id from log_customer where customer_id=2) 
  as log_customer2
on log_customer.log_id=log_customer2.max_id
where log_customer.customer_id=2;
```

oh damn...

```
select * from log_customer where customer_id=2 order by log_id desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Too bloated for such trivia question :-) Also I bet this query will have really weird execution plan

Comment: I missed too, that OP **does not want** query with `order by + limit`. See comments to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this way:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Log_Customer
 WHERE Customer_Id = 2
   AND Log_Id = (SELECT Max(Log_Id)
                   FROM Log_Customer
                  WHERE Customer_Id = 2)
```

A sub-select usually isn't bad as far as the execution plan is concerned.

Comment: sjngm, your remembering the existence and usefulness of subqueries fills my heart with hope for the future of mankind.

Comment: You can remove `Customer_Id = 2` from the outer query.

Comment: @Stefan H: you are very much aware that you posted a different answer. Note that comments on your answer!

Comment: Yes I did, while I was editing, you added yours.  You are more then welcome to look at all my sql formatting, that's who I format it.  I apologize if you think i tried to Steal your answer, i did not.

Comment: How come both answers are same except for leading whitespace and character case?

Comment: @Salman A: it is common to format sql in such way here at SO.

Comment: @Stefan H: You are very much welcome to look at all the SQL-code I wrote in the last 20 years! BTW, my edit was that I added the info about the execution plan (ask some admin if you don't believe me). Anyway, thanks for your apology.